# Mapping Visual Studio keyboard shortcuts in Xcode

Tags: visual-studio, xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

At work I use Visual Studio 2008 and at home I use Xcode 3.2 (and I love both of them).  But a major annoyance is the difference in keyboard shortcuts - I will be happily coding and then attempt to perform an autocomplete (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> in Visual Studio, <kbd>Esc</kbd> in Xcode) and a `GeneralTypingFault` will throw a `SwearAndHitYourDeskInAnger` exception.

Is there an easy way (some kind of plugin or script) to map Visual Studio shortcuts in Xcode or vice-versa without having to manually enter a [huge](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/files/Visual%20Studio%20.NET%202005%20Keyboard%20Shortcuts.htm) (or [somewhat huge](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2008/02/complete-xcode-keyboard-shortcut-list.html)) set of shortcuts?

Comment: Can you share your keyboard customization files for XCode - the ones that are based on Visual Studio. In fact there are two shortucts I add to visual studio Ctrl+Y as delete current line and Ctrl+W as close document.

Comment: +1 for SwearAndHitYourDeskInAnger exception

Comment: If you Google brought you here for the opposite (sort of i.e. VSCode instead of VS) check out my Xcode keybindings for VScode: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=stevemoser.xcode-keybindings

Comment: After almost 12 years, I have same question. not being able to use shortcuts are the only reason i'm switching to vscode for swift programs

Answer (score 2):

There is a 'Key Bindings' Menu in Xcode preferences with the option to import Sets of binds. perhaps there is a VS set you can download. Failing that you could (admittedly laboriously) set them up yourself.

Comment: @Kevin: If you do have to do this please make it available for people to download and let us know here!

Comment: See answer below by chaiwalla.  He includes a link to a MSVC compat keybinding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Metrowerkz Compatible" setting (XCODE->PREFERENCES->KEY BINDINGS). It's not a 1:1 mapping with VS, but it's a lot closer than XCode natively.

Answer (score 0):

Ive been trying to set my XCode keybindings up to mirror my Visual Studio ones (as I'm way more familiar with the VS ones).

The ones that give me a lot of problems are Visual Studios use of F keys - where on OS X a lot of the F keys are accelerators that pop up task switchers and so on.