# Keybinding in Xcode with two command keys mapped with character key

Tags: xcode, key-bindings

Basically my problem is, I'm a `Visual Studio` and `Android Studio` user and now I'm learning Swift so I'm using `Xcode`. Keyboard shortcuts of XCode is drastically different. So I searched for something to `export the VS keybinding to Xcode` but no success. I've checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430714/mapping-visual-studio-keyboard-shortcuts-in-xcode) but is of not much help.

If it's not possible to import whole set of keybindings then I'd love to bind some of frequently used shortcuts.

Here come my Problem. Is it possible to set the keybinding which includes two character keys.

for example:-

`commenting selected code` -> `"Command + K + C"`

`fold functions and methods` -> `"Command + M + O"`

like this, there are several shortcut keys which I'm unable to set in xcode.

I know it's quite longer than Xcode shortcut which is just `"Command+/"` for commenting code, but there are other shortcuts with similar pattern which i'd like to change.

ps- I'm using `xcode 12.4`

Comment: Whats wrong with Xcode > Preferences > Key Bindings?

Comment: thanks for attention. I have updated the question. basically I'm trying to set shortcuts mentioned in question, but I'm unable to set. Am I missing something here?